# Uncontrollable scrolling

Tags: windows-10, mouse, touchpad, scrolling

This started happening about an hour ago. I didn't install anything new, didn't restart the computer, basically did nothing. I noticed this first when I tried to use an online 3D human simulation. It was constantly zooming out. I'd zoom in, it would fight me, and after I stopped, it would continue to zoom out. I closed the tab, slightly annoyed by the *bad simulation*.
A bit after I opened Google spreadsheet and as I opened the tab, it would simply scroll to the left (not changing the cell selection). I don't know if I should call that scrolling, since it is basically jumping about three columns at a time. Also, it doesn't happen when the mouse isn't hovering the actual spreadsheet but is positioned elsewhere.
Next weird thing - as I open the start menu (Windows 10), the area where the mouse is hovering is scrolling down (not smooth either). This is happening with webpages only from left to right.
Also, when I'm scrolling a webpage with my mouse, it is very laggy, as if it is fighting with other input.
I disabled my mouse - it changed nothing. I disable both my mouse and my touchpad, again - nothing. As long as the mouse is hovering a scrollable area, it's scrollin' and I'm hatin'. Help?

Comment: Try restarting your computer.

Comment: I did. The problem still persists.

Comment: Also I cannot choose anything from a drop-down list since it disappears the moment i click on the box.

Answer (score 2):

I removed the USB thingy for the wireless mouse and put it back in and everything was fine again.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this same problem for a couple of hours trying many things.  I even turned off my wireless keyboard and mouse, using usb keyboard and mouse but the problem persisted.  Then I saw the comment about removing the "wireless mouse thingy" so I unplugged the logitech dongle that handles the keyboard and mouse.  Plugged it back in and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

You probably are a gamer...

- You may have an **Xbox controller** attached to your computer's usb port, detach it.

That controller is probably upside down or buried under something that is pushing the joystick down. The joystick is causing all the menus to scroll down from this surprising input source.

Screwed me up too.