# ZhiZhu ET X-08 scroll wheel

Tags: mouse, mouse-wheel

[This](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00SCUE9GQ) is the mouse. It was working fine 6 months and few weeks ago its scroll wheel just went nuts. It scrolls jerky, up and down, jumps unpredictably. Also, [something](https://superuser.com/questions/1161440/uncontrollable-scrolling/1161517#1161517) went wrong with the mouse a month ago, and I solved the problem. I have an Acer running Win 10. I tested the mouse on a Mac and it behaves identically. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you tried just cleaning it with compressed air and/or alcohol?

Comment: I did not. I'm not sure it can be taken apart, though.

Comment: The screw holes are usually behind feets at the bottom.